# Different search paths when searching using the new question page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, new-nav, navigation

I was just looking for a duplicate using the top search bar, so I typed `global-inbox`. I got this page:

> [image: first search page]

Here I can sort for `votes`, which I was looking for. Then I noticed I missed the tag brackets in the search, so I typed `[global-inbox]` and hit search again:

> [image: second search page]

The second search brought me to another search page as the first one... Now, since I am on the 'new questions' page, I can't sort on `votes` any more. Also, the UI is totally different, and I think there is still some merging left to do.

Can you:

- Make the second hit on `search` go to the same page, as the page before?
- Make us sort on `votes` in the 'new questions' page?

I noticed just now that searching for a tag in the top bar also brings me to the second search page. So if this is by-design, can anyone elaborate on the *why*?

Comment: That's not search, it's a tag page ([example in the old navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), where it clearly says "Tagged Questions") - the reason I opted out of the new navigation alpha testing is because it made search by tag a nightmare. Guess I'll have to get used to it once it's deployed, but personally hope it will never happen. Anyway - no bug here, that's just how the new navigation work.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I consider that a functional bug ;)

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed a while back with our top bar and questions listings redesigns. Searching for `[tag-name]` brings you to the tag page for that tag, where you now have the option to sort by votes (among other things).